# connecting to DB from java issue

Tags: java, database, database-connection

When I tried to connect to my DB from IntelliJ and after I insert to the modules the connector file the Run console wrote to me that issue:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value
>   'Jerusalem Daylight Time' is unrecognized or represents more than one
>   time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via
>   the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time
>   zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.

And this is the code:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/login","root","Password");
System.out.println("Connection: " + con.getCatalog());
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the mysql server time zone by using below command, and timezone will be as per your region.

SET time_zone='US/Eastern';

or

set time_zone = '-6:00';

it might be solve your problem

Comment: thank's it's worked

Comment: vote please.....

Answer (score 0):

Specify a timezone supported by MySQL in the connexion URL :

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/login?serverTimezone=UTC","root","Password");
```